# Docker desktop throwing an error while deploying it with powershell script

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I have a powershell script which should install Docker-Desktop with app on Windows Machine. After executing the powershell script it displays Docker Installed Successfully and through's an error message **"**error listing credentials -err:exit status 1,out:'A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.'"**.** This happens only on particular machine, when I run the same script on multiple windows machines the Docker-Desktop installation and the app installation is successful as desired. It even works fine on the Azure Virtual Machines on Windows 11 Home and Pro Edition. This installation is done with elevated privileges.

Write-Host "Installing Docker..."
start-process C:\Windows\System32\DockerInstaller.exe "install --quiet --accept-license" -Wait -NoNewWindow
cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
& 'C:\Windows\System32\DockerInstaller.exe'
$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin"
$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources"
Write-Host "Docker Installed successfully"
$shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$shell.minimizeall()
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework

```
    $Time=New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogon
    $p = "C:\PROGRA~2\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXX.ps1"
    $Action=New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument "$p"
    Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "XXXXXXXXXX" -Trigger $Time -Action $Action -RunLevel Highest -Force
```

A part of the shell script is as above. It installs the Docker-Desktop and before reboot throughs an error **"**error listing credentials -err:exit status 1,out:'A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.'"**.**

**Expected Behaviour**: On executing the powershell script it should install the Docker-Desktop and the app inside it.

Current Behaviour: On executing the powershell script it installs Docker-Desktop with an error message **"**error listing credentials -err:exit status 1,out:'A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.'"**.** and the docker desktop does not start.

Answer (score 0):

You can try again after remove the credStore line in the ~/.docker/config.json

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).